# How can I use database of mysql with android online application

Tags: java, mysql, laravel, sqlite, ionic-framework

Hello I have some questions please.
the situation is I have a web site made by Laravel using mysql database. And I need to create android application for this web site and the application use sqlite. how can I use the database of my web site to work with my application, and also make the data into sqlite when there's no connection in phone.
I need the idea in ionic and in java app please.

Comment: And of course [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bsqlite%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+sync)

Comment: there're any examples in ionic bro?@MadProgrammer